# Conditional logistic regression on matched data with replacement

Tags: r, logistic, odds-ratio, matching

I'm using 1 to 5 matching on my data with replacement, where each treatment is paired to at most 5 control units with the possibility of one control unit being assigned to more than one treatment.

What is the correct way to do conditional logistic regression in this case?

Can I just plug my matched data into clogit (I'm using R), or should I use some kind of weighting first? In case of weighting, am I right to think that only the control units should be weighted, with a weight of 1/(number of times assigned)?

Thanks in advance!